# Samba tools reporting "Unable to initialize messaging context"

Tags: samba

When running various tools that interact with Samba, I get the following message at the terminal:

> Unable to initialize messaging context

For example:

```
$ smbclient //localhost/$USER
Unable to initialize messaging context
Enter WORKGROUP\mattd's password: 

$ smbtree
Unable to initialize messaging context
Enter WORKGROUP\mattd's password:
```

What does it mean and why am I seeing it?

I am running Fedora 30.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to be a bug with the current smbclient (4.10.10) [1] and a fix has been included in the next release.

1. https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13925

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it meant that I needed to do `sudo smbclient [...]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to upgrade to the newest `smbclient` package easily. Since I am using `smbclient` for `get` commands only, I was able to work around this error by using `smbget` command instead. It's part of the same package `smbclient`.

Just wanted to share in case it helps anyone else in this situation.